# CSS-filter transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

my query is :
Whenever I press any button for the first time, the image successfully transitions to the desired filter in 4 seconds. But when I press another button the transition takes place immidiately without 4 seconds. How do I make the picture change in 4 seconds everytime I press the buttons?.

```js
function change_image() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "sepia(1)";
}

function change_image_2() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
}

function change_image_3() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "blur(5px)";
}
```

```css
#blur {
  transition-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="blur">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="whatever" height="400" width="300">
</div>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image()">Sepia</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image_2()">Grayscale</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image_3()">Blur</button>
```

Comment: I can't work out why the animated transition works only once, but at least I can say that you should factorise your functions. If you have 200 filters, will you repeat 200 times the same function? No, write only one and pass the filter as an argument : `function change_image(filter) {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = filter; }` and call it this way : `onclick="change_image('sepia(1)')"`, `onclick="change_image('grayscale(100%)')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to transition from one filter to an other, you need to have the same `<filter_function>` list inside your style declaration between the states.

It seems that otherwise browsers won't do the transition, even if you force to come back to `none`...

So the solution is to always declare all your `<filter_functions>`, and just set their argument to `0`.

```js
function change_image() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "sepia(1) grayscale(0%) blur(0px)";
}

function change_image_2() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "sepia(0) grayscale(100%) blur(0px)";
}

function change_image_3() {
  document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "sepia(0) grayscale(0%) blur(5px)";
}
```

```css
#blur {
  transition: all 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="blur">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300" alt="whatever" height="400" width="300">
</div>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image()">Sepia</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image_2()">Grayscale</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="change_image_3()">Blur</button>
```

---

I didn't checked completely the underlying reasons yet, but from fast-reading [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#interpolated-types), I would say that browsers would be able to use a correct number interpolation between same filters, but wouldn't with different ones.

Now how is it able to work out the first transition from `none` to any filter ?
One more mystery...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that your buttons can't transitate from greyscale(100%) to an undefined state. you should try your code by using the 3 style parameters on each buttons,
ex:

```
function change_image() {
    document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "sepia(1)";
    document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "grayscale(0%)";
    document.getElementById("blur").style.filter = "blur(0px)";
}
```

Hope i'd help.